# How to return object formed from two properties, one property (name) from one array and second property (value) from second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods, properties

I am suppose to write a method in which I have two parameters (two arrays), and method should return an object that has as many properties as one of the arrays has, property name should be given from one array, and value property from second array.
Thanks for the help in advance. :D

```
function reaction(array1, array2) {
    if (array1.lenght !== array2.lenght || array1.lenght === 0 || array2.lenght === 0) {
        return null;
    }
    let obj = {};
    array1.forEach((e1, e2) => { obj[e1] = array2[e2] })
  
    return obj;
};

console.log(reaction(codes, names))
```

Comment: hi, start by fixing typos in your snippet. Also, some input and output data would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create the resulting object from the input arrays.

This creates an object with a key named for each element in the first array, with a value from the second.

```js
function reaction(array1, array2) {
    if (array1.length !== array2.length || array1.length === 0 || array2.length === 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return array1.reduce((acc, key, idx) => { 
        acc[key] = array2[idx];
        return acc;
    }, {});
}

// Some examples to illustrate...
console.log(reaction(['length', 'width', 'height'], [3, 4, 5]))
console.log(reaction(['age', 'income'], [42, 55000]))
```

You could also use a simple for loop to achieve the same result, again using array1 as keys and those in array2 as values.

```js
function reaction(array1, array2) {
    if (array1.length !== array2.length || array1.length === 0 || array2.length === 0) {
        return null;
    }
    let obj = {};
    for(let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        obj[array1[i]] = array2[i];
    }
    return obj;
}

// Some examples to illustrate...
console.log(reaction(['length', 'width', 'height'], [3, 4, 5]))
console.log(reaction(['age', 'income'], [42, 55000]))
```

Comment: I have tried both of the solutions, both worked. I decided to go with reduce method because it looked more elegant :) . In general, I am importing two objects from another js file, and I was suppose to create a new object with property name from one object, and property value from second one.